# how to redirect back to my react app from a payment site

Tags: reactjs, payment

I have a requirement where I have to redirect to a third party payment website and after successful payment that needs to redirect back to my react app . I don't know how to do it and what will be the callback URL to my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use useHistory(); hook from react-router. Here is the guideline: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks

Just trigger it after payment is successful.

Comment: I got it. useHistory will allow me to redirect to the payment site. but how to redirect it back to my react app ?